# MassAction if I select all items I get NULL in the controller

Tags: grid, uicomponent, controllers, massaction

I have this grid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">employees_listing.employees_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">employees_listing.employees_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Employee</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/form</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="employees_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">
                Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">employees_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render" />
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">

        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions"
        class="\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Delete selected employee(s)?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete employee(s)</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="*/*/massDelete" />
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="calculate_average_age">
                <settings>                    
                    <url path="*/*/massCalculateAverageAge" />
                    <type>calculate</type>
                    <label translate="true">Calculate Average Age</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>

        <bookmark name="bookmarks" />
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls" />
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">
                                    Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">
                                    ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <paging name="listing_paging" />
    </listingToolbar>

    <columns name="columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>25</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="last_name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Last Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="date_of_birth">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Date of birth</label>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="age">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Age</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="role_description">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Role Description</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="role_type_description">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Role Type Description</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="NTTData\Employees\Ui\Component\Column\Actions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>

</listing>
```

In the massaction setion I have two actions, massDelete and massCalculateAverageAge, in both controllers if I select all of the items I get a NULL response. If I select one, or two or any number but not all of the items it works perfectly, but if select all even once, I get NULL.

Here are the controllers,
MassDelete.php

```
<?php

namespace NTTData\Employees\Controller\Adminhtml\Employees;

use NTTData\Employees\Model\ResourceModel\Employees\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;

class MassDelete extends Action
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $employeesFactory;
    protected $filter;
    
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Registry $registry,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $employeesFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->employeesFactory = $employeesFactory;
        $this->filter = $filter;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->employeesFactory->create());

        foreach ($collection as $employee) {
            $employee->delete();
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 employee(s) have been deleted.', $collection->getSize()));
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }
}
```

MassCalculateAverageAge.php

```
<?php

namespace NTTData\Employees\Controller\Adminhtml\Employees;

use NTTData\Employees\Model\ResourceModel\Employees\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;

class MassCalculateAverageAge extends Action
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $employeesFactory;
    protected $filter;
    
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Registry $registry,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $employeesFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->employeesFactory = $employeesFactory;
        $this->filter = $filter;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $selectedIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected');
        var_dump($selectedIds); 
        die();

        // si en algun momento se selecccionaron todos los empleados, el filtro devuelve vacio
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->employeesFactory->create());
        
        $totalAge = 0;
        $averageAge = 0;
        $count = $collection->getSize();
        
        foreach ($collection as $employee) {            
            $totalAge += $this->getAge($employee)->y;            
        }

        if ($count == 0){
            $averageAge = 0;
        } else {
            $averageAge = $totalAge / $count;
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Average age of selected emploees is: %1', round($averageAge, 2)));
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }

    private function getAge($employee)
    {        
        $birthDate = new \DateTime($employee->getDateOfBirth());
        $now = new \DateTime();        
        return $now->diff($birthDate);
    }
}
```

I tried with a var_dump inside the execute() function

```
public function execute()
    {
        $selectedIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected');
        var_dump($selectedIds); 
        die();

        // si en algun momento se selecccionaron todos los empleados, el filtro devuelve vacio
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->employeesFactory->create());
        
        $totalAge = 0;
        $averageAge = 0;
        $count = $collection->getSize();
        
        foreach ($collection as $employee) {            
            $totalAge += $this->getAge($employee)->y;            
        }

        if ($count == 0){
            $averageAge = 0;
        } else {
            $averageAge = $totalAge / $count;
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Average age of selected emploees is: %1', round($averageAge, 2)));
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }

    private function getAge($employee)
    {        
        $birthDate = new \DateTime($employee->getDateOfBirth());
        $now = new \DateTime();        
        return $now->diff($birthDate);
    }
```

And if I select some items:

[image]

I get:
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdhPN.png)=> string(1) "3" [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkvT7.png)=> string(1) "5" [3]=> string(1) "7" [4]=> string(1) "8" }

If I select all:

[image]

I get:
NULL